# R vertical scroll not working

Tags: dt, flexdashboard

I am trying to get a vertical scroll but this isn't working, can anybody explain why?  I would also like to default to show 20 rows at once.

Thanks

---

````
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
datatable(cars ,options = list(c(bPaginate = F, scrollY=T)),  filter = 'top')
```
````

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `scrollY` parameter isn't a boolean. You need to specify the fixed height of your table as [per the datatables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY).

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
DT::datatable(cars, filter = "top",
                    options = list(pageLength = 20, scrollY = "200px"))
```
````